# Regex to append a word after the occurrence of any word from a list

Tags: python, regex, nested-lists

Recently I got this amazing answer on how to remove a word if it occurs after any word in word list1. I wanted to remove the word eat.
I was wondering if it is possible to do the reverse, add a particular word after the occurrence of any word from a given list.

`list1 = ['duck', 'crow', 'hen', 'sparrow']`

`Input:[['Duck fish'], ['Crow veggies'], ['She lives there']]`

`Output:[['Duck eats fish'],['Crow eats veggies'],['She lives there']]`

```
import re

list1 = ['duck', 'crow', 'hen', 'sparrow']

look_behinds = '|'.join(f'(?<=[{w[0].swapcase()}{w[0]}]{w[1:]})'
                        for w in list1)

EATS_RE = re.compile(rf'(?:{look_behinds})\s+eats?\b')

sentences = [['The crow eats'],
             ['Hen eats blue seeds'],
             ['the duck is cute'],
             ['she eats veggies']]

repl_sentences = [[EATS_RE.sub('', s, 1) for s in x] for x in sentences]
print(repl_sentences)
```

```
OUTPUT

[['The crow'], ['Hen blue seeds'], ['the duck is cute'], ['she eats veggies']]
```

Is there a way to change the code to perform the reverse task? What can be the regex for the problem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you're asking for is simple; just use the appropriate regex to match the particular words only, and replace it with the matched word which has "*eats*" appended to it:

```
>>> r = re.compile(r"\b([cC]row|[dD]uck)\b")
>>> r.sub('\\1 eats', "crow here") # '\\1' is the placeholder for the 1st group in our match, i.e. the bird names surrounded with capturing parentheses in our case
'crow eats here'
```

However, what you likely want is not to add the word if it already exists. For this to happen, we use *negative lookahead* for a more careful match for replacement:

```
>>> r = re.compile(r"\b([cC]row|[dD]uck)\b(?!\s+eats\b)")
>>> r.sub('\\1 eats', "crow here")
'crow eats here'
>>> r.sub('\\1 eats', "crow eats here") # should remain unaffected
'crow eats here'
```

To update (reverse) your code, it will be something like this:

```
import re

words = ['duck', 'crow', 'hen', 'sparrow']
captured_word = '|'.join(f'[{w[0].swapcase()}{w[0]}]{w[1:]}' for w in words)

EATS_RE = re.compile(rf'\b({captured_word})\b(?!\s+eats\b)')

sentences = ['The crow',
             'Hen blue seeds',
             'the duck eats too much',
             'she veggies']

[EATS_RE.sub("\\1 eats", s) for s in sentences]
# output: ['The crow eats', 'Hen eats blue seeds', 'the duck eats too much', 'she veggies']
```

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/247761/discussion-between-sajad-and-codingamethyst).